# how to import a file into mathematica and reference a column by header name

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a TSV file with many columns like so;

```
genename    X1  X100    X103    X105    X115    X117    X120    X122    X123         
Gene20728   0.415049    0.517868    0.820183    0.578081    0.30997 0.395181
```

I would like to import it into Mathematica, and then extract and sort a column.

i.e., I want to extract column ["X117"] and sort it, and output the sorted list.

Answer (score 4):

```
table = Import["file.csv", "Table"];
x117 = Drop[table[[All, 7]], 1];
sorted = Sort[x117];
```

Comment: hi, I don't know what the column index for x117 will be on import. So do I have to read in the header/colnames first line and convert from colname to index on the fly?

Answer (score 4):

I do not think there is a built in method of achieving the smart structure you seem to be asking for.
Below is the what I think is the most straight forward implementation out of the various possible methods.

```
stringdata = "h1\th2\n1\t2\n3\t4\n5"

h1  h2
1   2
5   4
3

Clear[ImportColumnsByName];
ImportColumnsByName[filename_] := 
 Module[{data, headings, columns, struc},
  data = ImportString[filename, "TSV"];
  headings = data[[1]];
  columns = Transpose[PadRight[data[[2 ;; -1]]]];
  MapThread[(struc[#1] = #2) &, {headings, columns}];
  struc
  ]

Clear[test];
test = ImportColumnsByName[stringdata];
test["h1"]
test["h2"]
Sort[test["h1"]]
```

outputs:

```
{1, 3, 5}
{2, 4, 0}
{1, 3, 5}
```

Building on ragfield's solution, this is a more dynamic method, however every call to this structure makes a call to Position and Part.

```
Clear[ImportColumnsByName];
ImportColumnsByName[filename_] := Module[{data, temp},
  data = PadRight@ImportString[filename, "Table"];
  temp[heading_] := 
   Rest[data[[All, Position[data[[1]], heading][[1, 1]]]]];
  temp
  ]

Clear[test];
test = ImportColumnsByName[stringdata];
test["h1"]
test["h2"]
Sort[test["h1"]]
```

outputs:

```
{1, 3, 5}
{2, 4, 0}
{1, 3, 5}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, ImportString needs to be replaced by Import to operate on files.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from ragfield's code:

```
table = Import["file.csv", "Table"];
colname = "X117"
x117 = Drop[table[[All, Position[tb[[1, All]], colname]//Flatten]],
            1]//Flatten;
sorted = Sort[x117];
```

Answer (score 0):

For processing Excel files from various sites I do variations on this:

```
data = {{"h1", "h2"}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, ""}};

find[x_String] := Cases[Transpose[data], {x, __}]

In[]=find["h1"]

Out[]={{"h1", 1, 3, 5}}
```

If it is ragged sort of data you can usually pad it readily enough to make it suitable for transposing. Additionally some of my sources are lazy with formatting, sometimes headers change case, sometimes there is an empty row before the header, and so on:

```
find2[x_String,data_List] := 
 Cases[Transpose[data], {___, 
   y_String /; 
    StringMatchQ[StringTrim[y], x, IgnoreCase -> True], __}]

In[]=find2["H1",data]
Out[]={{"h1", 1, 3, 5}}

data2 = {{"", ""}, {"H1 ", "h2"}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, ""}};

In[]=find2["h1",data2]
Out[]={{,"H1 ", 1, 3, 5}}
```

Comment: You can use `Flatten[data, {2}]` to "transpose" a ragged array.  Also, I think your `find2` is rather dangerously broad in its search; if there is the possibility of a single empty string above the header, why not allow for that explicitly?

Comment: I was just giving a generalized answer but in doing so thinking about some of the stuff I regularly import. One data source I use almost has a different format each release. By which I mean whitespace padding of headers and one or more blank rows at the top. However the header -- however it may be spelled and padded -- is always the first and only string in a column. Thanks for the tip with Flatten for ragged lists. I didn't know that.

Comment: Why not change your pattern to account for blank lines at the top, but not arbitrary lines of other content.  E.g.:  `{"" ..., y_String /; StringMatchQ[StringTrim[y], x, IgnoreCase -> True], __}`  It just seems to me that finding *any* row in the column that matches a particular head is too broad.  (I would like to vote for this answer, but I am concerned that as written it may cause someone a lot of trouble.)

Comment: What can I tell you. My suggestion is a stylized answer. The code fragments I have posted are not ones I use because I know more about the data that I am routinely importing. More information about the nature of data a person wants to import leads to more specific code to import that data. But these are just generalized suggestions which by definition are broad.